# Instaling cross-compiled debian packages to fake "footfs" with dpkg

Tags: deb, dpkg, rootfs

The setup I have is like this: I have two sets of libraries that are compiled for *amd64* (pc) and *armelx* (ARM). They are both used to cross-compile some software on a build machine.

The first ones (amd64) can be updated without hassle by updating the apt-repository and using `apt-get install` on the build machine. The packages for ARM however, I don't want to install with apt, because it does not support installing to different directory. If I installed to default directories, the versions could not coexist. Right?

So far, the build machine was updated manually each time there was a new version of the packages, simply by extracting with `dpkg -x` to a dedicated "fake" *footfs* directory. This is where the compiler would also look when cross compiling other SW. The problem is, there is no information about these extracted packages or their versions anywhere on the system, right? It should have been in the *status* file.

My thought was to have these packages installed on this footfs dir with `dpkg -i <package.deb> --root=<rootfs>`. Would this work? I have a feeling it will not, because the deb packages have no post/pre-remove/install scripts, so it may work for a virgin install somehow, but not for upgrading? Also, what must the *rootfs* directory structure look like and what must it contain in order for this to work even the first time? Is there a tool to help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I realize now that this might be better suited for _superuser_ forum...

Answer (score 3):

Once you have a base armel Debian system, you can actually enter it and run the armel code inside it using something like QEMU. The `qemu-arm-static` tool (in the `qemu-user-static` package) can make use of the [binfmt_misc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt) capability in Linux to make it so ARM executables are directly run under the QEMU ARM system emulator. So you can run `dpkg`, `apt-get`, and so on inside the armel "rootfs" while running on amd64 hardware.

Example:

```sh
my_arm_system=/mnt/arm_system
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static "$my_arm_system/usr/bin/"
sudo chroot "$my_arm_system" apt-get update
sudo chroot "$my_arm_system" apt-get install $somepkg
sudo chroot "$my_arm_system" /bin/bash
```

As for setting up the base armel system in the first place: Debootstrap is the typical method for setting up a Debian base system, whether in a chroot or otherwise. You can use it for installing a base system of a different architecture, but it takes a few extra steps:

```sh
distro=jessie   # or whatever
echo "Debootstrap phase 1"
sudo mkdir "$my_arm_system"
sudo debootstrap --arch=armel --verbose --foreign "$distro" "$my_arm_system"
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static "$my_arm_system"/usr/bin/
echo "Debootstrap phase 2"
sudo chroot "$my_arm_system" /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

[Multistrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Multistrap) is another tool that might be useful; it is intended for setting up Debian environments of one architecture on a host of a different architecture, or for using more complicated APT source combinations. It's not perfect, as it doesn't follow all the deb installation "rules" exactly. It takes some shortcuts/deviations in order to make its job reasonably possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this isn't quite what I wanted. Perhaps I was unclear in my question, it's hard to explain the whole setup elegantly. My problem evolved a couple of times, as I was digging deeper. As I asked the question I was at the beginning of solving the problem, but now I'm a week into it. I'm not the only one working on this project and there are some restrictions on what to change and how.